# 3 point arc is concave or convex?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, arc-length

I have 3 points of arc like 
$$(x_1,y_1,z_1),\ (x_2,y_2,z_1),\ (x_3,y_3,z_3)$$ 
and I need to determine if it is concave or convex.

Can you help me ?

Comment: I doubt anyone can: the problem is way too underdetermined. One of many issues: what does convexity even mean for an **arc**?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the points
all lie in the same plane,
the question is meaningless,
because if you turn
a convex set of point
upside down,
it becomes concave.